# How to use If statements in SQL?

Tags: sql, if-statement

I am trying to create this if statement in SQL, would this be possible?

```
IF start2 >= start1 AND start2 <= end1, 
    group_start=start1 (ELSE start2)

THEN IF end2 >=end1,
    group_end=end2 (ELSE end1)
```

Comment: Look into SELECT CASE

Answer (score 4):

Not really clear what you are trying to do, but you generally use CASE-statements for this.
Try the below code and see if this is what you are after.

```
select case when start2 >= start1 
             and start2 <= end1 then start1 
                                else start2 
        end as group_start
      ,case when end2 >= end1 then end2 
                              else end1
        end as group_end
  from ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope it may b: if ok plz remember to mark as answer

```
declare @startDate date;
declare @workingDays int;

set @startDate=GETDATE();
set @workingDays=9;


if ((DATEPART(DAY,@startDate)=15 ) AND (@workingDays=5))
    print('asif')
    else if ((DATEPART(DAY,@startDate)=15 ) AND (@workingDays=9))
    print('mahamud')
    else if ((@workingDays>5)) 
    print('nop')
    else
    print ('99')
```